# SQL - with only showing a value greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to SQL. I have my code written out where I display a Vendor name and the total amt due for all of their invoices.  My issue is, I only need to display those Vendors that has a total greater than $0.00. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT VENDOR_NAME, TO_CHAR(SUM(INVOICE_TOTAL-PAYMENT_TOTAL-CREDIT_TOTAL),                                                            '$999,999.99') AS AMTDUE
FROM AP.VENDORS, AP.INVOICES
WHERE AP.VENDORS.VENDOR_ID = AP.INVOICES.VENDOR_ID
GROUP BY VENDOR_NAME;
```

Code displays:

[image]

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Isn't it odd how this is Oracle SQL but nobody seems to notice?

Comment: TO_CHAR is not a tsql function. Tag the dbms that you are actually using.

Comment: And why do you think DISTINCT is needed? Grouping by VENDOR_NAME will guarantee that you get one row for each value. DISTINCT does nothing useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT VENDOR_NAME,
       TO_CHAR(SUM(INVOICE_TOTAL-PAYMENT_TOTAL-CREDIT_TOTAL),                                                            '$999,999.99') AS AMTDUE
FROM AP.VENDORS V JOIN
     AP.INVOICES I
     ON V.VENDOR_ID = I.VENDOR_ID
GROUP BY VENDOR_NAME
HAVING SUM(INVOICE_TOTAL - PAYMENT_TOTAL-CREDIT_TOTAL) > 0;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases.
- Qualify *all* column names.  I don't know where they come from, but I would guess most should be preceded by `I.`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I cannot believe I did not think to put the HAVING clause after my group by clause.

Comment: @Bec - If the answer worked for you, you can appreciate the time & effort spent by others on answering your question by marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark beside the answer. Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL Server?